# How to alter many variables at once if they meet condition in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I have written a Bash script that reads various sensor readings and sets them as variables (for later saving to file).
If, for whatever reason, there is a bad reading and a variable has not been set, I need to change that variable to -999 (so that I know it's an invalid reading once they're all saved to a file).

I could simply do something like

```
if [[ -z "$latitude" ]]
then
    latitude="-999"
fi
```

(explicitly define the variable to test and replace)... but I have about fifty variables (which I will slowly add to over the next few months) so I would rather do this an easier/more flexible way, if possible, rather than hard-coding it.

I thought I might enter all the variables into an array, then do an if [[ -z VARIABLE]] test.

Here's some example code I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash
TypesArray=(latitude longitude elevation)

#code for setting sensor readings as variables is here but is redacted from this sample for brevity.

for i in ${TypesArray[@]}
do
    if [[ -z "$i" ]]
    then
        $i="-999"
    fi
done
```

(i.e. if the array element - which is a variable - is empty (as tested using -z), then set it to -999, and if it's not empty, then leave it as it is).

When I run this, I don't get any error messages, but the output for known empty variables ends up empty instead of -999.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your snippet.

**First problem**: When testing if a variable is empty, you tested instead whether the variable name is empty. Using parameter indirection `${!<varname>}` helps here.

From the bash manpage:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion.

**Second problem**: You've set the variable `i` to -999 -- eval helps here.

From the eval help page:

> Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the
>   shell,
>       and execute the resulting commands.

Here is the correct code:

```
#!/bin/bash  
TypesArray=(latitude longitude elevation)
for i in ${TypesArray[@]}
do
    if [[ -z "${!i}" ]]
    then
        eval $i="-999"
    fi
done
```

Comment: While `eval` can bring security risks, it's not harmful in every situation. There are definitely safe uses of `eval` - e.g., this one. Assuming the content of `TypesArray` is not set dynamically, I don't see a possibility how `eval` could be evil here.

Answer (score 3):

[Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) with [indirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78).

```
for i ...
do
  : ${!i:=-999}
done
```